# Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: 'use strict';

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, babeljs, isomorphic-javascript

While transpiling the following `index.js` file, I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: 'use strict';

I am using `babel-core`, `react`, `react-dom`.

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from './components/App'
import Home from './components/Home'
import FundDetail from './components/FundDetail'

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/fund/:id" component={FundDetail}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'))
```

My `.babaelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-strict-mode", "transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

Server Code:

```
    var React = require("react");
    var ReactDom = require("react-dom/server");
    var babel = require('babel-core');
    var Component;
    babel.transformFile("./assets/js/index.js", {}, function (err, result) {
      if(err) {
        sails.log.error(err)
      } else {
        Component = React.createFactory(result.code);
        var comp = Component();
        res.send(ReactDom.renderToString(comp));
      }
    });
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try removing `"transform-strict-mode",`, that should be handled by `es2015` already, so you may be adding it twice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `transform-react-jsx` isn't the only thing you need, why not use the preset? As you can [see](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-react/index.js) there is more than that transform:

```
npm i babel-preset-react --save
```

And add it to .babelrc:

```
"presets": ["es2015", "react"]
```

And remove the transform.

Also try `babel-core/register` on the server.

I'm also not sure what you're doing with `babel.transformFile`? Normally you just do something like:

```
server.get('*', require('./router'));
```

Where the file is exporting a [function](https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js#L63) which uses react-router's match. I haven't seen this approach before of requiring a index.js file (which isn't exporting anything) but doing a react render?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm trying to render "index.js" on the server when the it recieves a "GET /" request. I'm not using redux. The same "index.js" is the entry point on the client side app.

Comment: Ah ok, same applies without redux though - normally you would pass a match function as middleware and if a route matches you would be passed a Component by react-router and do `renderToStaticMarkup` on it - e.g. https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js#L24

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Ok, i tried what you suggested, and have run into another problem. Could you please help me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771970/implement-react-router-in-sailsjs